# Change button text in modal popup minicart

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, mini-cart, modal, modal-popup

When I remove an item in the Minicart, a modal popup pops up. This popup has two buttons: `Cancel` and `OK`. I want to change these strings to `No` and `Yes`, but I can't find the code where the modal is triggered.

I also don't want to translate `Cancel` and `OK` to `No` and `Yes` for obvious reasons. Where can I find the source for this?

Comment: Have you tried with template path hint ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala The modal popup is called via a Javascript function, I don't think it will be visible in the template hints

Comment: Just try once and chek

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Not visible, as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two buttons `Cancel` and `OK` is default values defined in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js`.

If you want to update these button (not use translate), you have to override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js`, where `confirm.js` is used, by copy it to custom theme `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/sidebar.js`.
Then change event binding for removing items like this

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery.Event} event
 */
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    confirm({
        content: self.options.confirmMessage,
        actions: {
            /** @inheritdoc */
            confirm: function () {
                self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            always: function (e) {
               e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: $.mage.__('No'),
            class: 'action-secondary action-dismiss',

            /**
             * Click handler.
             */
            click: function (event) {
                this.closeModal(event);
            }
        }, {
            text: $.mage.__('Yes'),
            class: 'action-primary action-accept',

            /**
             * Click handler.
             */
            click: function (event) {
                this.closeModal(event, true);
            }
       }]
    });
};
```

Comment: I have added the code you recommended, emptied the static content and emptied the cache, but I can't see any difference. Any idea why it doesn't work? The current sidebar.js file: https://paste.ofcode.org/6hEDjhka3HsPYcSRxTVZWE

Comment: I see no problem in your code. Please redeploy static content, clear browser caches and try again

Comment: With your help, I solved the problem by adding the code to my own JS